# How to import .ods?

Tags: r, import, ods, gnumeric, ssconvert

I'm trying to import data (.ods file) and I know how to import .csv, .xls etc. but I strand all the time. I tried it with the package Gnumeric but R tells me that the required program 'ssconvert' cannot be found.

Comment: Did you try to install the ssconvert package? https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnumeric-list/2013-November/msg00022.html

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as the questioner but i cannot install ssconvert (no such package?). Unfortunately I don't understand the answer "R does not look for ssconvert in the right place". I thought ssconvert is integral to gnumeric?

Comment: What os are you using? The "right place" is usually shorthand for making sure that the program is in your "PATH", in other words, can be found by programs calling it. On Linux it works without a hitch after installing gnumeric.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I wrote a package called `readODS`
which has a function `read.ods` that returns ods files as `data.frames`
(a list of `data.frames`, one per sheet)

It is available on CRAN, see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readODS/index.html)!

Source and bug reports here:
https://github.com/chainsawriot/readODS

Comment: Any change we'll get a version compatible with R 3.0.2 soon? I'm getting this message after running `install.packages("readODS")`: "package ‘readODS’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)".

Comment: i do not know how to add packages to CRAN for previous R releases, or how to check on what versions my package can run. can you try to build the package yourself? all i can find is: `http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_readODS.html`and it passes everything there... i added a bug report to my tracker, but i am unsure what to do with it tbh (`https://github.com/phonixor/readODS/issues/14`).

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate on `read.ods` vs. `read_ods` ;-)

Comment: According to your own docs, as of 1.6.2 `read.ods` has been deprecated and replaced by `read_ods`.

Comment: Although recently upgraded, I've tested this function and it's _awfully_ slow. Unless the authors do something to speed the reading, I will look for something else.

Comment: I've been using it, but my non-ascii letters like å import as <U+00E5> or as å arbitrarily. read_ods() is excellent for getting numbers from .ods-files though.

Comment: @MichaelChirico From [rdocumentation.org](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/readODS/versions/1.6.7/topics/read_ods): "*`read_ods` is a function to read a single sheet from an `ods` file and return a data frame. `read.ods` always returns a list of data frames with one data frame per sheet. This is a wrapper to `read_ods` for backward compatibility with previous version of `readODS`. Please use `read_ods` if possible.*"

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact problem on Ubuntu Linux.  It's frustratingly obvious:

> sudo apt-get install gnumeric

---

As it happens, I had a bunch of obsolete packages, and went thru a bunch to update them.  The `gnumeric` library requires the `XML` library, and my installation of `XML` library was built on 2.14, and my R wouldn't load anything built before 3.0.  I don't think that is your issue, but if this solution above doesn't work, maybe you could also check that your packages are up-to-date.  Anything I installed via `sudo` had to be removed via `sudo`, or I got permissions errors.

---

It's frustratingly obvious, because the error message is

> Error in read.gnumeric.sheet(file = fname, head = TRUE, sheet.name = "Sheet1") : 
>    Required program 'ssconvert' not found.

To emphasize it, the package documentation at http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/gnumeric/gnumeric.pdf says

> Requires an external program, 'ssconvert' (normally installed with 'gnumeric' (http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/) in 'PATH'.

How do you get `ssconvert`?  Again, frustratingly obvious: it's normally installed with gnumeric.  Go to the command line, and type `ssconvert`, and it'll remind you that:

> user@Computer:~$ ssconvert
>   The program 'ssconvert' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing: 
>   sudo apt-get install gnumeric

I checked, `ssconvert` isn't in the dependency packages (like `gnumeric-common`), it's in `gnumeric` proper, so you have to install the complete `gnumeric` package:

> sudo apt-get install gnumeric

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but the ROpenOffice package looks like it might do the job: http://www.omegahat.org/ROpenOffice/

Comment: I tried that as well, R tells me: 
ERROR: dependency ‘Rcompression’ is not available for package ‘ROpenOffice’
* removing

Comment: link not working?